# Compile type error when trying to return Extendable record

Tags: functional-programming, purescript

I have created an extendable record type and how can I return the minimal base type without the compiler throwing error.

I have a record with type,

```
type SectionContent r = 
   { titleText :: String 
   , subTitleText :: String
   , ....
   | r 
   }
```

I'm Extending it, like

```
type MyConfig = 
    { section1 : SectionContent ()
    , section2 : SectionContent (someContent :: {...})
    ..
    }
```

When I try to access in my code like this,

```
  -- This is inside another function & I have access to config
  currenScreenConfig :: forall r. SectionContent r 
  currenScreenConfig = if predicate 
                         then config.section1
                         else config.section2
```

It's throwing error,

```
Could not match type
                                                 
    ( someContent :: {...})                                            
                                                 
  with type
      
    r0  
.....
where r0 is a rigid type variable
    bound at ...
  ....
```

And what exactly **rigid** type mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic confusion about who gets to choose the generic parameters.

When you access (or "reference", or "use") a value whose type has a `forall r.` in front, you get to choose what `r` is. And whoever implemented that value must make it such that it would work with the `r` you choose. Without knowing what you will choose in advance.

In other words: **it's the caller of the function that gets to choose type parameters, not the implementer**.

Therefore, somebody calling your `currenScreenConfig` function later might decide to choose `r ~ ( foo :: String )`. And then your function would have to return a record `SectionContent ( foo :: String )`.

And another caller, in a different place, might choose `( bar :: Int )`, and then your function would have to return a record `SectionContent ( bar :: Int )`.

Do you see how there is no way to implement such function?

---

Now, if you want to return just `SectionContent ()`, then that's what the type of the function should be:

```hs
currenScreenConfig :: SectionContent ()
```

But of course with that you can't return `config.section2`, because it has a different type.

---

There are ways to "trim" a record (i.e. throw away unneeded fields). One such way is [the `pick` function](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record-extra/4.0.0/docs/Record.Extra#v:pick) from the `record-extra` package, which you could use like this:

```hs
currenScreenConfig :: SectionContent ()
currenScreenConfig = if predicate then config.section1 else pick config.section2
```

---

However, I encourage you to employ a more natural model instead. If the "common" part of the various screen contents is commonly extracted like that, it would be more natural to include it as a field rather than merge:

```hs
type SectionContentCommon =
  { titleText :: String 
  , subTitleText :: String
  , ....
  }

type SectionContent r =
  { common :: SectionContentCommon
  | r
  }

type MyConfig = ... same ... 

currenScreenConfig :: SectionContent ()
currenScreenConfig = if predicate then config.section1.common else config.section2.common
```

---

It may seem cool and shiny to use extensible records, but I strongly encourage you to consider a more straightforward model instead. Trust me: cool and shiny never outweighs long-term maintenance.